# OOB application - no connection to Server

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

I have a working Silverlight 4 application, also working in OOB mode;

Here are two scenarios: When I

1. Run Web version together with OOB version

   - OOB is working properly, server methods as well
2. Run OOB application only

   - OOB is starting, but server methods are not working !

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your server that host the methods are running using eg ASP.NET Development Server?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just found the solution:

I was installing the OOB from withing Cassini server, so logically it worked only when Cassini is up and running;

When I installed it from localhost, I experienced no problems at all...

thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: this has been resolved with latest updates. No you may just: 
1) go to SL Project properties and "enable running out of browser" checkbox. 
2) go to SL Project Debug and select OOB and choose your web application name in the combobox. 
3) make you SL App as startup object and disregard warnings about starting SL in wrong way because they are false (bug), you will see you app running well.